# Which data structure preserves order in python?

Tags: python, data-structures

I am looking for a data structure which allows fast search and also preserves the order of the data it received?

Comment: You can use an OrderedDict - https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict

Comment: For anyone finding this question in the modern era: sets and dictionaries in Python are now guaranteed to be order-preserving, starting in Python 3.7.  See https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict .  If this question weren't closed, I would add an answer recommending to use those as the canonical solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lists and tuples preserve order, dictionaries and set don't. An available ordered version of a dictionary is [`collections.OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict), which provides a faster search than a list.

Comment: Also: [Synchronized queues classes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html)

Comment: And [collections.deque](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/collections.html#collections.deque)

Comment: For numeric values, there is [array](https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html).

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [this](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html)

You have dictionaries and set:(**unordered**)

- Dictionary is `an unordered set of key: value pairs`
- set is `an unordered collection with no duplicate elements`

You can either use for **preserving the order**:

- list
- tuple
- collections.OrderedDict

Choosing the data structure totally depends on your requirement.

- List and tuple hold a basic difference. `List is mutable and tuples is immutable`
- ordered dictionary is nothing but a key value pair.

So you can choose accordingly!